# Is it possible to use only a part of an XML layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have a lot of XML layouts in my Android app as the layout of many ListViews.
Is it possible to mix them in one XML files and then read only specific part of that file for every ListView?
Is it a good idea to do this?

Comment: you mean re-using layouts? http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is a good idea to re-use layouts. use **include** tag to add a layout in another layout.

See the [developers website](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more detail with examples.

Also if you intend to make a single layout to use in all Listviews , then initially you have to set the visibility for all views as gone and then make it visible as per your requirement in listview.

Comment: If your intent is to use one node of a view tree than I think it could be done by inflating a view from XML and then use using the findViewById method of the inflated view to get a reference to a sub view.  

That said, Brontok's suggestion is the standard practice for doing this.